# Implement a function that creates a new linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, initialization

So I need to create a function in C that creates a new linked list. The function needs to Dynamically allocate memory for a new linked list of the list
type, Initialize all members of the created instance of the list type and Return a pointer to the new list. Im hung up on initializing all the members of the created instance.

These are the structs I have to use to create my new linked list.

```
typedef struct list {
    /**
     * @brief Pointer to head node of linked list
    */
    struct node* headPtr;
} list;
```

```
struct node{
    char* county_name;
    char* fips_code;
    char* seat;
    int population;
    int area;
    struct node* nextPtr;
};
```

***This is my function so far. ***

```
list* create_list(void){
    list* new_list = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    
    return new_list;
}
```

Should I just be declaring the variables inside the function like this

```
list* create_list(void){
    char* county_name;
    char* fips_code;
    char* seat;
    int area, population;

    list* new_list = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    
    return new_list;
}
```

When I do this I dont get any errors but Im not sure if this is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Create more functions: One to create a node, one to initialize the data of a node, one to add a node to your list. Then call each of them one by one, in a loop, to create an actual list with nodes.

Comment: I think I misread the problem I believe my function should be implemented like this 

`list* create_list(void){
    list* new_list = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    new_list->headPtr;
    return new_list;`
}
`

Comment: The statement `new_list->headPtr;` doesn't do anything useful. It doesn't do anything at all really. The compiler will likely not generate any code for it.

Comment: My suggestion is that you take a few steps back, and go through your learning material about linked lists.

Comment: Sorry typo it was supposed to be like this `new_list->headPtr = NULL;`. I did go back in my material and this is how the create_list function was set up.

Comment: Also this is just a single function in a list of functions that I need to create in order to generate my list. I will have other functions that can initialize data, add and remove nodes from my list. I appreciate all the replies @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for your time.

Comment: That function creates a `list` object, it initializes the `headPtr` to `NULL`, and returns a pointer to the `list` object. Is that the purpose of the function? Then it does what it should.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question with my first comment.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem at first which is probably why there was some confusion sorry about that. The purpose of the function was indeed to create a `list` object, initialize all the members of the `list` of which the only member was the `headPtr` and return a pointer to the `list`object.